# Improved phone validation pattern

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How could i write a pattern, which will help me to use only such inputs as valid:

```
+ 11111111
+ 11 1 1 1 1
+ 11 (11) 11 21
+ 11 (1-1) 11 1 1
etc
```

main troule is in that i must use only one + (which is first) only one (, ), and multiple time -, but! two time -- is wrong, but 1-2-1 is valid

only one single space is valid i mean `11 1      2   3` is invalid

is it real to write such huge pattern?

now i use one of this patterns:

```
[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}

^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$

\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}
```

from here: http://html5pattern.com/Phones

but there are a little bit to-hardcoded, i need some flexible solution, based on my examples above...

Comment: It would perhaps be easier to write a simple FSM-like parser, so it reads it character-by-character and checks if it's valid.

Comment: What kind of phone numbers are you trying to support?  Country specific?  International?  Can you give us some examples of what the numbers that you are trying to capture would commonly look like (as opposed to what people might enter)?

Comment: @talemyn International. Can you give us some examples of what the numbers that you are trying to capture would commonly look like (as opposed to what people might enter)? - all is in question

Comment: @MightyPork example please.

Comment: @Shaun and? what do you mean?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 - So a number with only 6 digits is valid (example #2)?  As is one with 8 (the other three examples)?  Can they be longer?  Shorter?  I think what is making this difficult to answer is the fact that you put "etc" at then end of your example number, which makes it hard to know if the four that you show actually cover all of the patterns, or if there is more that need to be taken into account.

Comment: @talemyn it could be 2 symbols, also it could be 20 symbols length, main trouble is with - + ()

Comment: @brabertaser1992 - Well, what I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way that you could be flexible enough to allow them to enter it in many ways and then convert it to a more standard format, as long as the value met some minimum requirements.  Using US numbers as an example, you can easily allow a user to enter `1234567890`, `123 456 7890`, or `(123) 456.7890`, and, as long as there are 10 digits present, reformat them into a standard `123-456-7890` after entry.  That allows flexibility for the users, but also provides regularity for storage and processing.